# How to implementation Basic Auth at Server side in Java using RestEasy? I have attached my filter as Java Code.Sample code has been attached

Tags: java, jax-rs, rest

```
@Provider
@Secured
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final String LOGGER_NAME  ="SecurityFilter";
    private static final String CLASS_NAME  ="SecurityFilter.java";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Logger.log(" requestContext: " + requestContext, LOGGER_NAME, CLASS_NAME, null, Logger.INFO, GroupId.ID);
        String authHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString("Authorization");
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Basic")) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(401).header("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic").build());
            return;
        }

        String[] tokens = (new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(authHeader.split(" ")[1]), "UTF-8")).split(":");
        final String username = tokens[0];
        final String password = tokens[1];

        if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("123")) {
            // all good
        }
        else {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(401).entity("Incorrect username or pass").build());
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

I am using RestEasy jar along with Java 1.8.
can anybody guide me ?
I have implemented the basic auth but its not working so look into this.

my Web.xml is given below

```
        <servlet-name>AvApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servicesyes/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
     <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/servicesyes</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>in.avenues.exh.test.SecurityInterceptor</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>in.avenues.exh.controllers.RESTApi</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
   </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AvApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>in.avenues.exh.controllers.RESTApi</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/error401.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/exhouse/secure/exceptionHandler.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error403.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>
            javax.servlet.ServletException
        </exception-type >
        <location>/exhouse/secure/exceptionHandler.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    
    <filter>
         <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>in.avenues.exh.controllers.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>SecuritFilterAuth</param-name>
            <param-value>in.avenues.exh.controllers.RESTApi</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>AvApp</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <!-- Add Security for RESTful Web Services Using Basic Authentication  -->
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>AvApp</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      
       <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>admin</role-name>
         <role-name>admin</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

   <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>admin</realm-name>
   </login-config>

   <security-role>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-role>
      <role-name>user</role-name>
   </security-role>
```

This is the web.xml file data.
beside this I have my end point
I need to implement basic auth to my end point to provide security.
I tried hard have not found any solution.
The ContainerRequestFilter looks like this

Comment: Do you have any relevant stacktraces that you are receiving in the current state?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd just like to handle basic auth, there's no reason to implement the filter yourself. You could just use the built-in mechanism of the server as described here:
https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.5.6.Final/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html.
In this case, you configure a security realm (e.g. via a simple realm.properties file) as described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms

I guess is that the filter is not registered with RESTeasy correctly. What you could also do is to do a check in the actual service using the @Context (javax.ws.rs.core.Context). This injects the security context as a parameter:

```
public void foo(@Context SecurityContext sc) {
  if (sc.isUserInRole(role))
    ...
  Principal p = sc.getUserPrincipal();
}
```

Likewise @Context can you be used to inject the Request object giving you access to the basic auth header.

Comment: I got the solution.
need to add 

<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
iside config.xml file iside
/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/userProject/config/config.xml
````
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
````